# tk.Textに文字列のエスケープシーケンスを正しく表示させたい。また、tk.Textに表示している行数を知りたい。

Tags: python, python3, tk

**やりたいこと**

1. tk.Textに受信したテキストファイルの内容（文字列）を表示させたい
   現状ではエスケープシーケンスの改行等を正しく表示することができません。
2. tk.Textに表示している行数を確認し、指定行数を超えたら古い順に削除したい。
   上記1に関連して、表示行数が多くなってきたら古いものを消したいのですが、行数の取得方法が分かりません。

どなたか対処方法をご存知の方はご教示をお願いいたします。

---

**テスト用テキストファイルの内容**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Tktest.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\'
             ],
```

tk.Textウィジットの表示
[image: tk.Text]

Comment: Tkinter側のコードを記載お願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**受信したテキストファイルの内容（文字列）を表示させたい**

「受信した」という処理が何を示していて、その時のテータ内容がどうなっているかに依ります。

1.改行コードが読み込んだ時のまま(0x0Aや0x0D,0x0Aの内部表現?)変数等に入っている

→そのままTextウィジェットに`insert`する

2.改行コードが既に \n の文字列に置き換えられて変数等に入っている

→変数の型がbytesなら`.decode('unicode-escape')`で、
strなら`.encode().decode('unicode-escape')`で変換してからTextウィジェットに`insert`する

参考
[Tkinter、Textウィジェットの使い方](https://narito.ninja/blog/detail/100/)
[Python3で文字列をUnicodeエスケープ／アンエスケープした文字列を得る](https://qiita.com/phonypianist/items/65ec69ac312936561cd7)

**行数の取得方法**

以下の方法で取得出来ます。

```
int(text_widget.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
```

参考
[Getting the total number of lines in a Tkinter Text widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609382/9014308)

---

例えば質問記事の「受信した」テキストの内容を sampletext.py というファイルに格納したとすると、以下のようになるでしょう。

```
# -*- mode: python -*-\n\nblock_cipher = None\n\n\na = Analysis(['Tktest.py'],\n             pathex=['C:\\\\'\n             ],\n
```

そしてプログラムとしては以下で動作確認できます。

```
# coding: UTF-8
import tkinter as tk

f = open('sampletext.py')
data1 = f.read()
f.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Editor Test')
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

text_widget.insert('1.0', data1)
text_widget.insert('end', '\n')

data2 = data1.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
text_widget.insert('end', data2)

print(str(int(text_widget.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])))

root.mainloop()
```

この時、行数は10でした。(最後の空行が含まれるのでしょう)
[image: Tkinter Text widget sample]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
stringの.decodeというのが分かりませんでした。Bytes型のメソッドのようですが。文字列データ（str型）にすでに出コードされた\\nなどが格納されて渡されてきています。

Comment: b_data = str.encode(data)
c_data = b_data.decode(b_data)
として2度変換すればよいということですね。

Comment: 2.で書いたように、データが格納されている変数が`b_data`で、受信/格納した時に既に改行コードが'\\n'になっているのなら、`b_data = b_data.decode('unicode-escape')`でしょう。

Comment: b_data がstr型の場合、decodeメソッドを使うと、例外が発生し、AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'と表示されてしまいます。一度、.encode('unicode-escape')でbytes型に変換し、.replace(b'\\\\',b'\\')でエスケープシーケンスを変換し、.decode('unicode-escape')で戻すことで表示することができました。

Comment: そうでしたか。確認プログラムの処理とは型が違うということですかね。ではもう少し調べて記述を修正しておきましょう。

Comment: お手数をおかけいたします。